# Samsung Galaxy s6 Music Player Track Sort

Tags: settings, music-player, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Okay, I have tried google and here and cannot find the answer to this. When I transferred all of my music from my s4 to the s6, it worked correctly but all of the tracks are in reverse alphabetical order (Z-A). The only settings within the music player are "Sound Alive, Play Speed, Music Auto Off, and Smart Volume". I cannot find any way to alphabetize the music (A-Z).

I haven't had the phone long so I might just not know of some other new navigation to this feature but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have been searching for a solution to this for a few days and have finally found one.

1. Open music
2. Top left drop down menu, go to tracks

If you only want to have it in alphabetical order in the app, stop here, if you want to fix the widget as well continue.

3. Go to more in the top right, edit
4. Top left, select all
5. Press more again, add to playlist
6. Create a playlist
7. Play a song in the playlist and go back to the home screen widget

This should fix the order :D

Comment: Thank you so much Tom!! This is exactly what I was looking for. So glad you could help.